# Вывод товаров по фильтру bitrix

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, битрикс

проблема возникла в том, что нужно по отдельной ссылке выводить только акционные товары на этой же странице. Фильтр выводится аяксовым методом только при клике на кноку "Акции". Аргументы в ссылку не передаются, да и вообще никуда не передаются, кроме текущей страницы. Как лучше будет сделать подобную штуку? Спасибо[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что этот вопрос нужно задавать на форуме поддержки продукта

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете создать отдельную страницу, которая будет полностью идентична текущей, но при вызове компонента списка товаров передать в фильтр необходимый параметр :)

Comment: Спасибо, так и сделаю)